# No ACPI support for my PC, what can I do?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, acpi, multi-core, amd-processor

On my new PC something is wrong with ACPI support under Linux. I have to boot it with acpi=off and nolapic. Also it detects only one CPU core (this annoys me the most) and won't shut down completely, I have to hold power button for few seconds to power PC off.

The question is: what can I do? Edit some config files? Report bugs? Send mails to motherboard manufacturer? Run some utility to help reverse-engineer drivers? (Currently I just turn AMD C1E off in BIOS. It's a nice workaround.)

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 12.04 (upgraded from 11.10)
- Processor AMD FX(tm)-4100 Quad-Core
- RAM 8,00 GB
- Graphic Gigabyte GV-N56GOC-1GI (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560)
- Mainboard Gigabyte GA-870A-USB3
- Disk ATA OCZ-AGILITY3 (SSD)

Comment: Why do you have to boot with both `acpi=off` & `nolapic`? What happens if you do not use those kernel options? Having only one CPU core is apparently a result of disabling ACPI. See this question: [**Is SMP running on my computer?**](http://askubuntu.com/q/127815/52923)

Comment: @irrational-john Without them system won't boot (this applies both to live and installed systems).

Comment: Also if I can help fix it (by providing some dumps or command outputs for example), I would do it.

Comment: Tell me, are you running 12.04.4? I found on my laptop, I had the same issue with you on 12.04.4 or later in Ubuntu and Lubuntu. So I went to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ and downloaded 12.04.3, and guess what.. worked! Did you want to try that and see if it does the same for you? If so, something has changed in acpi 12.04.3 > 12.04.4 that has stopped it working on some computers.

Comment: @user264771 I ran every Ubuntu from 11.10 to 13.10 on this PC. 12.04 was a first release, not a point release. I just disabled AMD C1E in BIOS and it all works now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you start by trying to follow the steps in this guide: [**DebuggingACPI**](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI).

The description at the top of that page says it is part of [Debugging Central](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProcedures), "*pages with debugging details for a variety of Ubuntu packages*" on the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/).

You should also try looking at the entries in `/var/log/syslog` to see if anything there  will help isolate the problem.

Make sure the portion of the log you look at is from a failed boot. That is, the log entries should be from a boot where neither `acpi=off` nor `nolapic` were used. The log timestamps should allow you to determine which boot a log file entry is from.

If you find it easier to use a GUI application, Ubuntu has a `Log File Viewer` which you can use. It can be found by searching for it using `Dash`. [image: Dash icon from my desktop]

The steps below are (pretty much) copied from the [DebuggingACPI page](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI) and are what I suggest you do to try to isolate the problem before filing a bug report. (I believe the procedures for reporting a bug are also on the [DebuggingACPI page](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI))

---

If `acpi=off` allows the system to boot, try to isolate the ACPI issue with the following boot parameters. Remove `acpi=off` and boot with **only** one of the options below.

If you are lucky, you might find a combination of kernel parameters which allows you to boot and use all the cores of your CPU.

**Note:** If you need an explanation of to how to do a "one time" change of the kernel boot parameters/options, try this [answer to the question "How do I add a kernel boot parameter?"](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/52923).

- Try booting with `acpi=ht`
  This disables all of ACPI except just enough to enable Hyper Threading.

  If `acpi=off` works and `acpi=ht` fails, then the issue is in the ACPI
  table parsing code itself, or perhaps the SMP code.
- Try booting with `pci=noacpi`
  This disables ACPI for IRQ routing and PCI scanning.
- Try booting with `acpi=noirq`
  This disables ACPI for IRQ routing.
- Try booting with `pnpacpi=off`
  This disables the ACPI component of the Linux Plug and Play code.
- Try booting with `noapic`
  Disables the IO-APIC for IRQ routing or PCI scanning.
- Try booting with `nolapic`
  Disables the local APIC.

---

Comment: I reported a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007508

Comment: Only `acpi=off` and `noapic` work for me. What are the cons of using `noapic`? What I will loose using it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better workaround than disabling ACPI (by using acpi=off and nolapic). **You can just turn AMD C1E off in BIOS!**

It still is an issue though...