# How do I install Ubuntu on an HP G62?

Tags: installation, graphics, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I've tried to install Ubuntu 11.04 and 12.04, but I have the same problem on both.

I proceed like this: I restart my computer, the language menu shows and I select my language, and then select to set up Ubuntu.
Then I get a black page, and nothing else.

I have an ATI graphics card. My laptop is an HP G62 series.

What should I do to make the install work?

Comment: I hope someone helps. my laptop is giving me the same problem, i have an Asus F50sv. i can get 10.04 on it (the normal way) but 11's and 12.04 goes black screen right after first purple screen. then i tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/129116/12-04-wont-boot-from-livecd-or-usb), and got to install it but when i restarted pc. it wouldnt boot past the purple loading screen. just goes purple right after.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) should help you solve the problem.