# Installation is failing

Tags: boot, graphics

I posted a YouTube video explaining what's wrong. Any help would be awesome!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQgwMwT5n-Q

Comment: Just press `Enter` on that purple screen. You should get `Try Ubuntu` & `Install ubuntu` options. First do `try ubuntu`. If any grpihcs problem occurs, post here

Comment: Please add hardware specs to your question. For graphic card issues [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/134081/3940).

Comment: Possibly one of the two the approaches I tried to outline in [**this answer**](http://askubuntu.com/a/135288/52923) might work for you. If I had to pick I guess I'd suggest trying to install using the Alternate CD. That installer is text based which is klunkier, but also less likely to have a problem with graphics.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ubuntu?
I saw that problem in the past, with a maybe 8.04 and I was able to solve it with the "alternate" version, so I can suggest to try the alternate versions of 12.04:

[ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso.torrent (32 bit)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso.torrent)

[ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent (64 bit)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)