# I can't start ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, 12.04

My system is:

> CPU intel 8400E, video card Ati HD6850, motherboard Gigabyte P31, 2x2GB DDR2 corsair, HD WD 250 GB (order of partitions no1 "\boot" 700 mb, ext3; no2 "\" 32 GB ext3; no3 "swap" 2gb, rest ntfs).

During installation all went fine (no display errors, desktop resolution was correct identify & set 1680*1050, I manage to set up internet connection & installed the updates).
Then I restart PC as Bbuntu demanded.

Soon after the problems occurred.
1. the screen was split in 2 vertically. I see the login screen, entered the psw and => next problem

1. All I see was the Ubuntu desktop colour but no icon or toolbar or something to choose, just an empty desktop split in two

3 All this time, from login till I restart PC the screen was flickering very very fast (after 10 secs of watching my eyes start to hurt)

I mention no error message appears neither something to tell me what to do.

I really hope you can help me with some explanation/advice, I don't understand why is this happening.

Thanks so much for your understanding!

Comment: Is it a bit like this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135372/why-is-my-ubuntu-doing-this

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking the Ubuntu logo on the login menu and selecting **Unity 2D** or **Gnome classic**. The problem may lie with the proprietary AMD drivers installed during installation. If you don't need full-featured 3D acceleration, you might just want to go to Hardware Drivers and remove the proprietary drivers (the open source ones are just as good in most non-gaming cases). Good luck!