# "Unknown keyword in configuration file Boot:" error when booting off a live USB 

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb

I successfully followed instructions in 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent
to make a bootable usb drive for ubuntu12.04 using the command 'gksudo usb-creator-gtk' in a terminal window - there were no error messages and the final pop message said I can now use the USB drive to successfully boot a system into the latest Ubuntu 12.04

However, on a brand new samsung laptop (NP-300E5Z-A0PIN - a i5 core machine), I get the following message:
SYSLINUX 3.63 Debian-2008-07-15 EBIOS Copyright (c)1994-2008 H Peter Anvin
Unknown keyword in configuration file
Boot:

It hangs there...

Am I missing out any steps... how do I proceed with the installation...
Many thanks in advance

Comment: This also happened when I tried booting on a ACER aspire 4710 laptop that I run an older version of ubuntu (and on which I made this bootable USB drive)

Comment: Did you check the md5sum of the iso ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 13):

I found this site, hopefully this will help you.  [Click Here](http://alexsleat.co.uk/2010/11/27/how-to-fix-unknown-keyword-in-configuration-file-ubuntu-usb-boot/)

Below is the solution from that site:

After creating a USB bootable version of Ubuntu from the Startup Disk Creator (or usb-creator-gtk) and attempting to boot, I was greeted by the error above. It might look a bit scary but it’s really easy to fix, just plug the USB flash drive into a computer (windows or linux, mac too probably but I haven’t tried that.)

**Solution 1:**

```
Open the the syslinux folder in the root of the flash drive.
Inside is a file called syslinux.cfg you’ll want to edit that.
Find the line “ui gfxboot bootlogo” and simply remove the “ui “.
Save and try booting again.
```

Below is how my syslinux.cfg file looks after editing:

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
gfxboot bootlogo
```

**Solution 2**

Alternatively it looks as though there is another way of fixing this issue if there is no “ui” in the file, this is to do as followed (as pointed out in the comments below):

```
Type “help” and press enter
Hit Enter again
```

This should boot correctly and shouldn’t need to be done every time.

<sup>Source: [http://alexsleat.co.uk](http://alexsleat.co.uk/2010/11/27/how-to-fix-unknown-keyword-in-configuration-file-ubuntu-usb-boot/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot.... it worked.... Guess the original distribution should have been fixed long back....

Comment: Solution 2 worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `usb-creator` depends on `syslinux-legacy 3.63`, and uses it to write boot up informations into USB, while the parameters "ui" can only be accepted by `syslinux 4.05`, which was installed on ubuntu 12.04.

A simple solution to solve everything is:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/syslinux-legacy /usr/bin/syslinux-legacy.bak
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/syslinux /usr/bin/syslinux-legacy
```

And you can actually use `syslinux 4.05` to write boot information into USB.

Comment: I used usb-creator many times, This problem wasn't there. It may not be the main cause.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message when installing Arch Linux (last release, around July 2018) and what I got is:
    SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 Copyright (C) 1994-2013 H. Peter Anvun et al
    No child node, aborting
    Unknown keyword in configuration file: PATH
    boot/syslinux/whichsys.c32: not a COM32R imagw
    boot:

I made the usb drive using a pointed usb creator (linked in Linux Mint's site, lol).
I tried using the above answers, but nothing happened to work, neither there is command `help`, so what i did is hit TAB and i got three commands listed - `select` (didn't do anything), `pxe` (it started the GUI installation, so it works well) and `sys` (which also acts like `pxe`, but gives a little bit different options). Good luck.