# 12.04 failed install

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Unknown keyword in configuration file Boot:” error when booting off a live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141311/unknown-keyword-in-configuration-file-boot-error-when-booting-off-a-live-usb)

Running 9.04 (see launchpad question #198606). Downloaded ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso, ran USB Startup Disk Creator (which installed 100% on USB drive), boot from USB fails.
“Unknown keyword in configuration file.
boot:”

Comment: Are you wanting to upgrade from 9.04 to 12.04 or just have a USB bootable device?

Answer (score 2):

The above error can be fixed by the following options:

1. Open the the syslinux folder in the root of the flash drive.
2. Inside is a file called syslinux.cfg you’ll want to edit that.
3. Find the line “ui gfxboot bootlogo” and simply remove the "ui".
4. Save and try booting again.

Here is the sample syslinux.cfg file:

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
gfxboot bootlogo
```

You can solve the problem by typing `help` and pressing enter twice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try Unetbootin. Install it from Software Centre. Much better and easier to use and RELIABLE.