# Booting the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installer from USB stick

Tags: usb, live-usb

I receive the following rather cryptic error message when following the [instructions on how to create a bootable USB stick on Windows on ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) using Windows 8:

> SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 Copyright (C) 1994-2013 H. peter Anvin et al
>
> Unknow keyword in configuration file: \╨╤
>
> No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!

I did find the very similar question [“Unknown keyword in configuration file Boot:” error when booting off a live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141311/unknown-keyword-in-configuration-file-boot-error-when-booting-off-a-live-usb) on askubuntu. However none of the proposed solutions work in my case. There is no `syslinux/syslinux.cfg` on the USB stick and entering `help` at the boot prompt doesn't have any effect either.

Could the error message `\╨╤` indicate an encoding issue with either one of the configuration files?

Update:

The contents of /uui/syslinux.cfg read as follows:

```
# This file was automatically populated by Universal USB Installer - http://www.pendrivelinux.com
prompt 0
DEFAULT append

LABEL append
CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
APPEND /isolinux
```

Comment: I decided to use http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ instead. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP graciously noted, *unetbootin* solved the problem. It was probably a corrupted download; using `md5sum -c DOWNLOADED.ISO` before creating the LiveUSB is recommended.