# Ubuntu install from inside windows

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, windows

I've been trying to install ubuntu from my usb flash drive but it keeps giving me the same "unknown keyword" error. I've already tried to change the names in xlinux.cfg and the others, but what comed up was that when I removed the flash drive from my PC it was getting corrupted (I noticed from the wrong content from isolinux.cfg and missing files).

Since I presume it's my flash drive's fault, I've thought if there's no way to install ubuntu in my HDD from inside the windows 10 running on my desktop.

EDIT: I don't think I let clear that I am trying to install ubuntu on my second computer, whose HDD are clean. My main computer, which I was referring to, has only windows 10.

Comment: Ubuntu will not run *inside* windows, it is an independent operating system that does all of the things Windows tries to do.  You can either run Ubuntu as a *Dual Boot* system, in which you reboot your computer and run Ubuntu **instead** of Windows, or you can install a Virtual Machine program, and run Ubuntu within the Virtual Machine.  Common Virtual Machines include VirtualBox and VMWare

Comment: I want to install ubuntu in another HDD FROM windows, not IN windows, so i would not need the flash drive

Comment: How are you putting Ubuntu onto your flash drive?  I know people have talked occasionally about using a HDD for installation media, but I've not seen it done.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I've tried with Universal USB Installer and YUMI, both gave me the same result

Comment: And the problem is that the computer will not boot from the USB?

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes, "unknown keyword in configuration file" error

Comment: I have had issues booting from USB before, but I'm somethign of a novice at resolving them.  Are you using UEFI and secure boot?

Comment: @CharlesGreen No, the computer which I am trying to install ubuntu is clean, it only has the bios

Comment: K - If possible, you might try a different USB.  What I've read and experienced indicate that the less expensive USB devices seem to work better for this, and the sandisk devices that I can get at my local supermarket work quite well.  The bigger (16 GB) devices I get elsewhere do not work for me at all...  Did you try the instructions in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141311/unknown-keyword-in-configuration-file-boot-error-when-booting-off-a-live-usb) - it is a bit old, and may not be applicable to Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: [This post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) talks about the 'bootability' of various USB devices in Ubuntu, and also has some hints about the BIOS settings.

Comment: @CharlesGreen already tried that answer, same result. Yes, I'll get another flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the awnser youre looking for. not sure.

Be sure to have 2 harddisks in your computer.

Disconnect the harddisk where windows is installed.
Get the ubuntu installation on an usb/cd.
Let your computer boot via the usb/cd.
Install ubuntu. (on the harddisk you want it of course)
Turn computer off and connect harddisk again.
You can now swap via OS on bootop of your pc. (Button depents on your computer, Like F8,F9 or F12.)
There are a lot of videos If you need any help.

Comment: Not exactly. My goal is to avoid the use of my flash drive, since I think it's not working fine.

Comment: What format is it? Did you test the drive?

Comment: It's beeing formated to FAT32, the Universal USB Installer standart action when creating a bootable device