# Booting Ubuntu with "acpi=off" grub parameter

Tags: boot, grub2, acpi

In order for me to boot into 12.04, I have to add the parameter `acpi=off` in **grub**. Any other options as specified [**here**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI) do not allow me to boot into Ubuntu.

My question is simple, what does setting the parameter `acpi=off` actually do?

And more importantly does repeatedly booting with `acpi=off` damage or harm the computer in anyway?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `acpi = off` disables your [Advanced Configuration and Power Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)
 off temporarily while booting Ubuntu.  If you have to add the `acpi = off` to let ubuntu boot successfully, it means that the ACPI on your computer isn't compatible with this version of ubuntu.

I don't think using `acpi = off` repeatedly wrecks your computer, because it only disables ACPI temporarily.

However, if you don't want to add the `acpi = off` parameters every time you boot, you can [disable the new card (BIOS)](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/995187/) or disable [ACPI (also from the BIOS)](http://www.ehow.com/how_7641485_edit-acpi-bios.html).  Use the second option if you can't find the New Card Interface.

But, if you have Windows, disabling ACPI from the BIOS **may wreck Windows and the computer will force you to reinstall it**.  So do that if you have a hidden windows recovery partition in your computer.

Comment: How should disabling ACPI harm Windows? It disables ACPI-usage in the Linux kernel, but not modify the ACPI-table on the BIOS. Windows can't be affected.

Comment: I actually disabled ACPI from the BIOS myself, and windows got an error of having "a serious problem" when I booted it.  Fortunately, the computer had a hidden recovery partition (which I didn't know) and fixed the problem by itself.  Then I searched online and found a bunch of people (no recovery partitions) that had to reinstall windows after disabling ACPI from the BIOS.  But I'm also not so sure why.

Comment: Ah - you disable it in the BIOS, not in the GRUB boot-options? I thought you talked about the latter.

Comment: Oh.  I edited the question.  Sorry for causing confusion.

Answer (score 14):

I've recently purchased a HP Envy 17 j053ea machine to take advantage of the i7 and oodles of memory. Cutting to the chase I suffered from many issues with this install. The wireless didn't work, the screen "black screened" during installation and thereafter during booting. The get around for the black screen was the boot option `acpi=off`, but this of course meant that the laptop would not suspend when I closed the lid which is clearly suboptimal. After searching for the past two days I have found many good articles/explanations of acpi and a much better option:

For info on acpi see: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/ACPI-HOWTO/

For more info see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ACPI_modules

Then I found:
[No ACPI support for my PC, what can I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127989/no-acpi-support-for-my-pc-what-can-i-do) from irrational_john ... way to go .. `acpi=ht` didn't work but `pci=noacpi` has done the trick. For your hardware I'd recommend John's approach pf cycling through the options he provided:

```
nolapic
noapic
acpi_osi=“Linux”
acpi_osi=“Windows 2006”
acpi=ht
pci=noacpi
acpi=noirq
pnpacpi=off
```

With this in hand abd to address “wub's” .. on point answer above, once you find the one that works:

```
bash# cd /etc/default
bash# sudo vi grub
# Use the vi editor to add the boot options to the line  

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

and make it (in my case):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash pci=noacpi”
```

finish with:

```
bash# sudo update-grub
bash# sudo reboot
```

Comment: I found that the options in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` show for the default linux option but are missing in the recovery menu option. How do you add apci=off to the recovery menu option?

Comment: @Sukima Add the options to ‘GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX’ instead for them to be added to both entries

Answer (score 0):

Windows simply does not start without ACPI. I got a Sony laptop 'defect', because there is no way to change ACPI in BIOS, so Sony wanted to replace the motherboard for a huge amount of money. Btw. Windows will not be broken or harmed in any way with no ACPI, it simply does not start.
Linux Ubuntu 20.04 works fine with that Sony - except - `acpi=off` disables also the Touch Pad. Tried `nolapic` and `noapic` plus `acpi=off` in all variations. Touch Pad did work but sometimes the Sony hangs in boot, error is non-deterministic. Only sole `acpi=off` without Touch Pad is stable.