# MSI Laptop touchpad does not work in Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: 16.04, xorg, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I have an MSI GE72 laptop and the touchpad simply does not work. My output of `less /proc/bus/input/devices` is :

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event0 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=600702900000 8380207af040d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0461 Product=4e22 Version=0111
N: Name="PixArt USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:0461:4E22.0002/i
nput/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=ff0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

and my output from `xinput` is :

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I do have an optical mouse plugged in so I can use the GUI but cannot get Ubuntu to recognize my touchpad at all. I have installed xserver-xorg-input-synaptics already as well as xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev and neither made my touchpad get recognized. I am rather new to linux so any troubleshooting suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I founded the problem. Is necessary to put "acpi=on" on the grub, in order to activate the irq controller properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh man thank you so much for responding to this! I've been carrying a mouse around with me lol. I will try this asap and report back

Answer (score 1):

This link helped me to fix the issue [Booting Ubuntu with "acpi=off" grub parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139157/booting-ubuntu-with-acpi-off-grub-parameter?newreg=bcc3315ec49942cba955f4bf85302dc9)

```
$ cd /etc/default
$ sudo vi grub
```

Use the vi editor to add the boot options to the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

and make it (in my case):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash pci=noacpi”
```

Finish with:

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo reboot
```