# My laptop does not recognize the network card in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

From Google Translate:

I installed Ubuntu 16 and 18 on my HP envy laptop and it does not recognize the wireless network card, although it does recognize the local one. Can someone help me solve this? It should be noted that it works perfectly in Windows.

Original text:
he instalado ubuntu 16 y 18 en mi laptop hp envy y no reconoce la tarjeta de red inalambrica, aunque si reconoce la local. alquien podria ayudarme a ssolucionar esto? cabe destacar que en windows trabaja a la perfeccion

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is an **English only** website, please use English for your posts (even if you have to run them through Google Translate first)

Comment: I've translated the text using Google. Perhaps now release the hold flag?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "the local one"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my previous HP laptop. After going to numerous forums, repair shops and hp customer care, the conclusion was as follows:

The ACPI drivers were incompatible ([Booting Ubuntu with "acpi=off" grub parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139157/booting-ubuntu-with-acpi-off-grub-parameter)) and hence would not allow access to the wireless card. (This also caused my laptop to not recognize the battery).

The issue seems to be unfixable (barring the purchase of a new laptop - you can find systems which work with Ubuntu here : https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/).

However, you might want to try finding the relevant drivers before you head out for a new laptop (you might find it here if it is by Intel: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005559/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html).

Also, the cheapest solution would be to use an Ethernet cable.