# Trouble with booting into Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, acpi

Recently i had a few attempts to install Ubuntu on a second hard drive. On the first one i have installed Windows 10. After doing what's here [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives), Ubuntu boots only if i type "acpi=off", after pressing "e" key while choosing "Ubuntu" in Grub. I have tried installing 18.04 LTS version before but result was same as above. Is there any way to avoid adding "acpi=off" in Grub?

Comment: Added acpi=off to /etc/default/grub sorry not sure about the option

Comment: i meant this https://askubuntu.com/questions/139157/booting-ubuntu-with-acpi-off-grub-parameter