# about acpi bug/error newly installed 22.04

Tags: acpi

ı recently upgraded new Ubuntu 22.04 lts, everything works fine but having ACPI bug report while startup. any thoughts/helps?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You have a bug in your BIOS that the kernel errors out on. Set  `acpi=off` during boot and permanently in defaults grub. See for instance: https://askubuntu.com/questions/139157/booting-ubuntu-with-acpi-off-grub-parameter

Comment: With `acpi=off` it dose not boot up. I tried the previous kernel (5.13.0-40-generic) that work before upgrade. Wit hat, it boot correctly but here is no wifi. Because the previous ubuntu version worked fine it is probably not a bug in BIOS but in the kernel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Same here... and GPU was not working...

Instead of loading the final kernel, I picked the previous version (5.13.0-40-generic) on grub and it worked.