# Ubuntu runs real slow, then crashes installing nvidia driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

Here's the hardware:

- P4 2.4ghz (32bit)
- 2 gigs ram
- Asus dvd burner
- MSI GeForce 5200 FX
- 1 Seagate 60 gig (IDE)
- 1 WD Black 80 gig (IDE)
- USB mouse
- PS2 keyboard
- 17" NEC LCD

Software:

- Ubuntu 13.1

Default install (Full)
I let Ubuntu setup disk and Partitions
Allow install of updates and 3rd Party Software.

Install goes fairly well maybe a bit slow but otherwise.
Get to reboot screen
Reboot
Hangs after Bios.
Reset
Very SLOW boot to OS! 12 minutes!!
Moving around VERY SLOW!
FireFox 3.5 minutes to load.
Video drivers loaded are default NOT Nvidia
I find the place to load drivers it finds the card and attempts to install and run.
After install OS freezes can't recover so did reboot.
No video at all now.

I see there are other flavors like Kubuntu and Lubuntu would these be a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

:-( I've had all sorts of problems with nvidia drivers and Ubuntu 13.10 ... In the end (and you won't like this answer) after bricking my laptop several times and trying PCLinuxOS, Mint, and others I resorted to nouveau drivers on Ubuntu 13.10 .. the trick is NOT to click the "Allow install of updates and 3rd Party Software" on installation ... other things encapsulated here from my journey of Linux Ubuntu install discovery ... https://askubuntu.com/a/406426/234481

Hope this helps in some way ... also stick with nouveau ... don't install nvidia .. a waste of processing capability I know but I'm hoping a comprehensive fix will come soon .. I've tried up to 331.16 (new 334 out but I've a project to finish first ..)

Comment: Thanks for getting back!  I did brick the install!  SO I'm about to right now to do a re-install. I'll assume I'll be able to get these Nouveau drivers during/after the install process. I won't check of on the install updates or 3rd party stuff. I'll do those manually. We'll see what happens in the next coule of hours. I hope using the Nouveau drivers fixes the bog down!

Comment: .. Nouveau part of the distribution .. basically (as best as I can figure) the default driver set for 13.10 .. http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/ ... good luck with it ..

Comment: Yea nothing worked! Not even Nouveau. I ended up with LUbuntu. It works a lot better, but even at that it seems a tiny bit slow. I haven't had the time to mess with it lately. In the next few days I will and see how it fairs then.  Thanks