# Ubuntu 13.10 goes completely black after signing in after i cleaned my system with bleachbit

Tags: login, screen, bleachbit

it was all working fine, unless i cleaned my system using bleachbit. it isn't the first time i am using bleachbit. but this time, something went wrong. after bleachbit completed its operation, my system started showing filled hard disk (no free space at all). how come this happened? i thought a restart might resolve this. when i restarted, the login screen appeared. but when i logged in, the screen went black with only the cursor displayed on it. this happens everytime i try to start my pc. i tried everything suggested on the net, but nothing worked.

need help.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be coincidental .. I've had many many black screens of death with Ubuntu 13.10 on my HP Envy 17" ... by any chance

a) Did you before the Bleachbit do a System Update? 
b) Did this update the graphics drivers? Could this be the problem? 
c) Can you escape to the comman line with ?

This might help https://askubuntu.com/a/406426/234481

Comment: yes, the system was updated, but i don't think the drivers were. that was about a day earlier than this black screen thing. it was only after that bleachbit cleaning operation that my hard disk started showing up completely filled. after the reboot, that black screen started coming up.

Comment: however, it is quite a surprise that the system goes black only after i log into my computer. before that, that is, after a system startup, the login screen appears perfectly. can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: i am sorry, but that link wasn't of much help to me. i am quite sure that this black screen definitely has to do something with that filled drive of mine. i guess, solving the latter would automatically solve the former.....

Comment: np ... thanks for feedback .. simple idea for stripping the drive back to working order is boot from usb key, mount the filesystems and delete the offending files to get back to working/freespace drive .. good luck with it ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. It asks for login credentials and you complete them, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> every time
3. `startx`

I've used Bleachbit to clean up two Ubuntu machines, and they've ended up having the same issue. The Ubuntu logo keeps blinking... but the solution I've been using is as above.

Comment: So you have to login on tty and then `startx` every time you boot? Doesn't sound like an effective solution to me.

Comment: That's the half-solution, I've come with. I'm still searching for a really nice one.