# Live USB of Ubuntu 18.04.2 or later not booting without "acpi=off" or "nolapic"

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, 20.04, acpi

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 in my desktop but live usb did not boot showing only a blank screen.

Following the instruction below, I found that only when I added `acpi=off` or `nolapic`  (and `nomodeset` because of nvidia gpu) to the kernel option, but the PC recognized only a single core of a cpu and the installation failed. Other options (e.g. `acpi=ht`) did not work.

https://askubuntu.com/a/132817/1420960

Trying several distros, I also found that Ubuntu 18.04.1 works but 18.04.2 or later does not. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and then upgraded it to 20.04, and confirmed that my PC works with kernel 4.15 but not 5.4.

How can I install Ubuntu 20.04 in my desktop?

- CPU: Intel Core i9 10980XE
- RAM: 128 GB
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
- MB: X299-S01A

Comment: What is the question? Your hardware supports what it supports.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 & 18.04.1 media install using the GA kernel stack, ie. 4.15 (Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack options; GA or HWE and the ISO used to install selects the default; unless changed).  Your *working* stack uses the GA stack option for 18.04 assuming you're talking about a desktop install (You didn't specify; 18.04.2 used 4.18, 18.04.3 used 5.0, etc before 18.04.5 which used 5.4; though 18.04.2 will upgrade to 18.04.5/5.4 stack).  Ubuntu 18.04.2 & later media defaults to HWE; with 20.04 Desktop all ISOs (excluding *flavors*) default to HWE by default.

Comment: @David I'm sorry. I just want to install Ubuntu 20.04. So, my question is how to do that?

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for your explanation. Can I use GA stack for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: The wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack provides a section "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel*" which tells you how, however the 20.04 GA stack is the final HWE stack of 18.04 (ie. 20.04 was released with it's GA stack, which gets ported, tested & released as 18.04.5 which was ~4 months later; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/)   16.04 with the HWE stack ended up with 18.04's GA stack, likewise 14.04 HWE used the GA stack from 16.04; the prior LTS ends with the GA stack from the next LTS release.

Comment: If you install with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS; the GA stack is default (you can switch to the HWE stack at install time if you so wish, the desktop ISOs don't have that option with the change needing to occur post-install for desktop systems).  I'll use Lubuntu as example, but Lubuntu 20.04 & 20.04.1 media defaults to GA stack too (ie. *flavor* media), but 20.04.2 & later defaults to HWE which was the default for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (all ISOs).  Note: some *flavor* media can use OEM kernels meaning GA wasn't default for 20.04 & 20.04.1; why I used Lubuntu as example; no OEM complication

Comment: Check that your motherboard firmware is up to date.  I have seen this problem fixed (on a Ryzen 2400G) with a firmware update.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for you kind instruction. But I can use only the default kernel attached to the live usb (which does not work for my machine)...

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes, I confirmed there is no release of update on BIOS from the manufacturer...

Comment: Given we don't know what ISO you've used; we don't know what kernel that is (5.4? 5.8? or 5.11? given ISOs exist for 20.04 for all three & that's not a complete list as I'm skipping OEM kernels)